# Windows Phone 8 images not showing if loading via HTTPS

Tags: internet-explorer, web-applications, windows-phone-8, user-agent

In my web application I have both http and https static images. i.e. some of them are being loaded from amazon web servers.

IE in nokia lumia 520 is not showing those images.

This is my user agent:
    Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 520)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please follow the "Problem, question, Code, exception" format for posting here if you would like an answer

Comment: What do you mean? why negative to my question? it's a valid question, just because formatting is not OK it can't receive negative votes

Comment: If you fix your formatting I will remove my downvote. This is how stackoverflow works. You ask a good question, you get points and probably an answer too. You ask a bad question or improperly formatted as in your case, you get downvotes and likely no answer. The point of proper formatting is to allow people to easily find your question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue (Nokia Lumia 520 also), and discovered that doing an update on the phone fixed the issue.